# UITapGestureRecognizer on 5 UIImageView

Tags: cocoa-touch

I have 5 UIImageView and one UITapGestureRecognizer, but when I tap on my UIImageView the method set as selector doesn't work. I've already set numberOfTaps as 1, but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UIImageViews default to having user interactions disabled. Make sure you call:

```
[myImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

Comment: EDIT: The gestureRecognizers array of my UIImageView is empty :(

Comment: Are you calling setUserInteractionEnabled:YES *before* you add a gesture recognizer?

Comment: Yes, I solved but in another way :P I've created an UIImageView and then self.view equal to that imageview. Remove that it works :/